# JavaScript String.prototype.split() called on a single character strange behaviour

Tags: javascript

I open url `http://localhost` where I load my js script.

Inside my js script I execute:

```
'use strict';

    var path = window.location.pathname;

    console.log(path); // it prints /

    var arr = path.split('/');

    if (arr.length === 0) { //actual length is 2
        console.log('test'); //not executed
    }
```

So `test` is not printed and my `arr` contains two elements and they are empty. Why does length of the array equal 2?

Comment: You'll get two parts, everything before and after the `/`. Since your input is `/`, youll end up with two empty strings. `split` is not a strip function.

Comment: _“and my arr contains two elements and they are empty. Why?”_ - because there wasn’t anything to the left or the right of the `/ ` to begin with, so if you split that at the slash, you are left with two “empty halves” ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are located in `/` (root of the server). If you use `/` as a separator in your `split`, you will have `n+1` elements, `n` being the number of separators in your string.

In other words, you end up with `path` being equal to `[THING 1]/[THING 2]` (both things being empty strings) which gives you an `arr` containing `['', '']`.

Your `arr` has length 2, both elements being empty strings.

Comment: Thanks! I've been thinking it has to return empty array like in some other languages :(